# Convert Token from ValueHelpDialog into Filters in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am using a `ValueHelpDialog` with range support. So these tokens are generated based upon selection and values entered. e.g. For '`contains`' a Token like `*abc*` is generated and for '`equal to`', `=abc` is generated. These tokens can be fetched on clicking `OK` on the `ValueHelpDialog` as seen below.

[image]

I need to create a `sap.ui.model.Filter` for these selections. How can I evaluate the Tokens to retrieve FilterOperator and the value to be filtered?

Kindly assist, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the filter data from the token with the [data](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/data) function.

```js
const oProperties = oToken.data("range");
/*
{
  exclude: false,
  operation: "Contains",
  keyField: "PROPERTY_PATH",
  value1: "abc",
  value2: null
}
*/

const oFilter = new Filter({
  path: oProperties.keyField,
  operator: FilterOperator[oProperties.operation],
  value1: oProperties.value1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can directly get the operator. Follow below steps to get it onclick of ok button on valuehelp dialog.

1. oEvent.getParameters().tokens
2. expand the result of above step and go to maggregations->customdata